# pandas - How to check consecutive order of dates and copy groups of them?

Tags: python, date, pandas

At first I have **two problems**, the first will follow now:
I a dataframe df with many times the same userid and along with it a date and some unimportant other columns:

```
    userid   date        
0    243     2014-04-01   
1    234     2014-12-01   
2    234     2015-11-01   
3    589     2016-07-01   
4    589     2016-03-01
```

I am currently trying to groupby them by userid and sort the dates descending and cut out the twelve oldest. My code looks like this:

```
df = df.groupby(['userid'], group_keys=False).agg(lambda x: x.sort_values(['date'], ascending=False, inplace=False).head(12))
```

And I get this error:

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 6 to array axis with dimension 12
```

At the moment my aim is to avoid to split the dataframe in individual ones.

---

My second problem is more complex:
I try to find out if the sorted dates (respectively per group of userids) are monthly consecutive. This means if there is an date for one group of  userid, for example userid: 234 and date: 2014-04-01, the next entry below must be userid: 234 and date:2014-03-01. There is no focus on the day, only the year and month are important.
And only this consecutive 12 dates should be copied in another dataframe.
A second dataframe df2 contains the same userid, but they are unique and another column is 'code'. Here is an example:

```
         userid  code
0          433805  1
24          5448   0
48          3434   1
72          34434  1
96          3202   1
120         23766  1
153         39457  0
168         4113   1
172         3435   5
374         34093  1
```

I **summarize**: I try to check if there are 12 consecutive months per userid and copy every correct sequence in another dataframe. For this I have also compare the 'code' from df2.
This is a version of my code:

```
df['YearMonthDiff'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: 1000*x.year + x.month).diff()
    df['id_before'] = df['userid'].shift()
    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for group in df.groupby(['userid'], group_keys=False):
        fi = group[1]
        if (fi['userid'] <> fi['id_before']) &  group['YearMonthDiff'].all(-1.0) & df.loc[fi.userid]['code'] != 5:
            final_df.append(group['userid','date', 'consum'])
```

At first calculated from the date an integer and made diff(). On other posts I saw they shift the column to compare the values from the current row and the row before. Then I made groupby(userid) to iterate over the single groups. Now it's extra ugly I tried to find the beginning of such an userid-group, try to check if there are only consecutive months and the correct 'code'. And at least I append it on the final dataframe.

On of the biggest problems is to compare the row with the following row. I can iterate over them with iterrow(), but I cannot compare them without shift(). There exits a calendar function, but on these I will take a look on the weekend. Sorry for the mess I am new to pandas.

Has anyone an idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: It is best to ask one question per question.

Answer (score 3):

for your first problem, try this

```
df.groupby(by='userid').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='date',ascending=False).iloc[[e for e in range(12) if e <len(x)]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupby` and `nlargest`, we get the index values of those largest dates.  Then we use `.loc` to get just those rows

```
df.loc[df.groupby('userid').date.nlargest(12).index.get_level_values(1)]
```

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
dates = pd.date_range('2015-08-08', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        userid=np.arange(2).repeat(4),
        date=np.random.choice(dates, 8, False)
    ))

print(df)

        date  userid
0 2015-08-12       0  # <-- keep
1 2015-08-09       0
2 2015-08-11       0
3 2015-08-15       0  # <-- keep
4 2015-08-13       1
5 2015-08-10       1
6 2015-08-17       1  # <-- keep
7 2015-08-16       1  # <-- keep
```

We'll keep the latest 2 dates per user id

```
df.loc[df.groupby('userid').date.nlargest(2).index.get_level_values(1)]

        date  userid
0 2015-08-12       0
3 2015-08-15       0
6 2015-08-17       1
7 2015-08-16       1
```

Comment: It's very close, but I search for the latest 12 months:
`
df = df.drop(     ~   df.groupby('userid')['date'].nlargest(12).index.get_level_values(1))`
I want the 12 latest months and drop all the other entries. I showed this with ~ sign, but of course it's only bitwise. How could I drop all the other entries?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone is interested, I solved my second problem thus:

 I cast the date to an int, calculated the difference and I shift the userid  one row, like in my example. And then follows this... found a solution on stackoverflow

```
gr_ob = df.groupby('userid')
gr_dict = gr_ob.groups
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['userid', 'date', 'consum'])
for group_name in gr_dict.keys():
        new_df = gr_ob.get_group(group_name)
        if (new_df['userid'].iloc[0] <> new_df['id_before'].iloc[0]) & (new_df['YearMonthDiff'].iloc[1:] == -1.0).all() & (len(new_df) == 12):
            final_df = final_df.append(new_df[['userid', 'date', 'consum']])
```